# Silverlight: Bing Map Control in OOB possible?

Tags: silverlight, bing-maps, silverlight-oob

I'm playing with the Bing Map control for Silverlight and an out-of-browser (OOB) app. I get the "map loaded in unsupported uri scheme" error because the control does not like to be hosted on the file system and wants a WebApplication instead (http://). Here's a more detailed explanation I found to this:
http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2009/03/silverlight-virtualearth-map-control.html

Is there a workaround to this when running a OOB app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bing Maps Silverlight control requires the application it's used within to be hosted on a web site or application. You are running it within an HTML page that is opened locally (not hosted within IIS or other web server.) That is why the specified error message is being shown.

This is a requirement of how the Bing Maps Silverlight control works.

[http://pietschsoft.com/post/2011/01/26/Bing-Maps-Silverlight-and-an-Out-Of-Browser-(OOB)-Application.aspx](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2011/01/26/Bing-Maps-Silverlight-and-an-Out-Of-Browser-%28OOB%29-Application.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's messy but it could work:

- Write a WinForms program that contains a `WebBrowser` control
- Embed a lightweight web server running on localhost into the program
- Serve your Silverlight application via a web page to the browser

That's a lot of work to make it look like you don't have a browswer and it's still not OOB.